# SSIS - package working only when there is breakpoint

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a SSIS package which contains different sequence container, the problem is when I execute the whole package, it executes first 2-3 containers then gets Index out of bound error in next container (In a script task inside a data flow task).

But when I put a debug point inside the script component, it executes fine and throws no error. Even if I execute each container separately, then there is no error. I am totally confused with this, any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's how it's getting the sequence container? By debugging/executing each container individually you're giving it more time to obtain the containers - so when you run the whole package, it could be that it's taking too long to get the container

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.